Write from ArcGIS Pro into n:m tables in SQL Server database
I would like to use ArcGIS Pro to access an existing structure in SQL Server (see image) with editing options. In addition to the columns listed, the MainTable also has spatial information (X Y points). The goal would be to be able to click on a point in the MainTable and add properties to it via the mapping tables. So there should be a selection list (reference table) that is displayed, then something is selected from it and the corresponding ID is transferred to the assignment table.
I have writing access to the SQL Server DB via "Windows-Authentification" and I also have a working connection in the ArcGIS Pro Catalog to my DB, but I dont know how to set everything up right with "relates"/"dependencies"/"joins"
Is that / and if so, how possible?

